# jQuery selector to add button below COMPOSE in Gmail

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add button underneath COMPOSE button in Gmail but no matter how far I traverse up, I always get the same selector.

This is the selector I am using
`$('[gh="cm"]').closest("div").closest("div")`

All of the following return the same element

1. `$('[gh="cm"]')`
2. `$('[gh="cm"]').closest("div")`
3. `$('[gh="cm"]').closest("div").closest("div")`

Comment: `$('[gh="cm"]')` must be a `div`. So the closest `div` to a `div` is the element itself. So all the three statements are the same.

Comment: Yes [gh="cm"] is a div. But I expect first `closest` to return the same element as closest starts with the element itself but shouldn't closest.closest give me the parent DIV?

Maybe I am missing something. Haven't used jQuery for many years now. But how can I get Grand Parent div of the selector ?

Comment: To get the grand-parent, just do `$('[gh="cm"]').parent().parent();`

Answer (score 0):

`closest()` will also check the current element, so if it is `<div>` it will be the filtered result

Try

```
$('[gh="cm"]').parents("div").first()
```

Comment: Tried running this from Chrome Dev Console and it throws error - `VM33773:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parents is not a function`

Comment: `$` is not set as a `window` variable. Try with `jQuery(...).parents(...)`.

Comment: @Treast I have injected it and the reason I can use closest. Let me check the jQuery version.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Have the latest version of jQuery

Comment: ok. The issue is when I always get String for `$('[gh="cm"]')` instead of jQuery object and hence can not call parent() or parents() method on it.

But I tried a similar selector in another site and it return jQuery Object

Comment: Doesn't make sense that $(selector)` returns a string unless there is something else overriding `$()` in the page

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but looks like Gmail overwrites jQuery.

I just ran the above code in setTimeout and it worked.

Why it didn't work earlier is still a mystery :)

Thanks!